# Page not found error in Codeigniter: Call to undefined function form_open()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to enable user registration and login in codeigniter.
But getting error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\application\views\signup_form.php on line 10

Any suggestion 
my url look like this

**/localhost/myfolder/index.php/signup/**

I create Controller

```
<?php
class signup extends CI_Controller {

    function Home(){
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index(){

            $this->load->view('signup_form');

    }
}
?>
```

signup_form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Contact Form Using CodeIgniter</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<?php echo form_open('main_controller'); ?>
<h1>Create Contact Form Using CodeIgniter</h1>
<?php echo form_label('Student Name :'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname')); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Student Email :'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail')); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Student Mobile No. :'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dmobile', 'name' => 'dmobile')); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Student Address :'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'daddress', 'name' => 'daddress')); ?>
<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function form\_open() in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063174/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-form-open-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
function Home() {
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('form');
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('signup_form');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to load `form` helper to use `form_open` method.

```
$this->load->helper("form");
```

**Edit**

If you need only in index method, just put it in that. If you need it in a lot of method in controller, just put it in constructor. Try to avoid loading unnecessary files. It can reduce memory consuming matter.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: where should i place it ?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this.

```
<?php
    class Signup extends CI_Controller {
         public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: sucess done

but when i try to login getting error

`A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146

Table 'tablename.user' doesn't exist`
url is
`http://localhost/myfolder/index.php/user/login`

Comment: Have you create `user` table in your db ??

Comment: There is one question related to this. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908843/a-database-error-occurred-error-number-1146-in-codeignitor

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass helper array in parent like

```
$this->load->helper(array('form'));
```

most of we need 4 type of function to pass in helper array

```
$this->load->helper(array('text','html','url','form'));
```

this is basic helper array url will help you to pass the base_url();